# Update state in useEffect shows warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I want to update a state after some other state is updated:

```
export default function App() {
  const [diceNumber, setDiceNumber] = useState(0);
  const [rolledValues, setRolledValues] = useState([
    { id: 1, total: 0 },
    { id: 2, total: 0 },
    { id: 3, total: 0 },
    { id: 4, total: 0 },
    { id: 5, total: 0 },
    { id: 6, total: 0 }
  ]);

  const rollDice = async () => {
     await startRolingSequence();
  };

const startRolingSequence = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
        setDiceNumber(num);
      }, (i *= 1.1));
  }

    setTimeout(resolve, 2600);
});
};

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!diceNumber) return;
    const valueIdx = rolledValues.findIndex(val => val.id === diceNumber);
    const newValue = rolledValues[valueIdx];
    const {total} = newValue;
    newValue.total = total + 1;

    setRolledValues([
      ...rolledValues.slice(0,valueIdx),
      newValue,
      ...rolledValues.slice(valueIdx+1)
    ])

  }, [diceNumber]);



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={rollDice}>Roll the dice</button>
      <div> Dice Number: {diceNumber ? diceNumber : ''}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-forest-ld9vu?file=/src/App.js)

When the user rolls the dice, a couple setTimeouts will change the state value and resolve eventually. Once it resolves I want to keep track of the score in an array of objects.

So when I write it like this, it works but eslint gives me a warning of a missing dependency. But when I put the dependency in, useEffect will end in a forever loop.

How do I achieve a state update after a state update without causing a forever loop?

Comment: It’s complaining specifically about the dependency rolledValues, have you tried adding it to the dependency list?

Comment: When I add it, it will update on each update, which will cause a forever loop, I updated the question with a link to a sandbox

Comment: That is specifically the dependency that is missing from the list of dependencies. Can you clarify why you need to use useEffect for these state updates? Can you instead update `rolledValues` in `rollDice`?

Comment: Here is an example of that in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-butterfly-jqgz9

Comment: you are right, that would work, however, I forgot something important, I execute a bunch of timeouts to simulate a rolling dice. Hence I have to wait till the state is updated until I can update the score keeping array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to set it up that keeps the use effect and doesn't have a dependency issue in the effect: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-keldysh-wf8cp?file=/src/App.js

This change in the logic of the setRolledValues call includes getting rid of an accidental mutation to the rolledValues array which could potentially cause issues if you were using it in other places as all React state should be worked with immutably in order to prevent issues.

The setRolledValues has been changed to use the state callback option to prevent a dependency requirement.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!diceNumber) return;

    setRolledValues(rolledValues => {
      const valueIdx = rolledValues.findIndex(val => val.id === diceNumber);
      const value = rolledValues[valueIdx];
      const { total } = value;
      return [
        ...rolledValues.slice(0, valueIdx),
        { ...value, total: total + 1 },
        ...rolledValues.slice(valueIdx + 1)
      ];
    });
  }, [diceNumber]);
```

I wouldn't recommend working with it like this, though as it has an issue where if the same number is rolled multiple times in a row, the effect only triggers the first time.

You can move the logic into the rollDice callback instead, which will get rid of both issues that was occurring. https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-visvesvaraya-402o1?file=/src/App.js

I added a useCallback around rollDice to ensure it doesn't change references so it can be used within useEffects.

```
  const rollDice = useCallback(() => {
    const num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
    setDiceNumber(num);
    setRolledValues(rolledValues => {
      const valueIdx = rolledValues.findIndex(val => val.id === num);
      const value = rolledValues[valueIdx];
      const { total } = value;
      return [
        ...rolledValues.slice(0, valueIdx),
        // newValue,
        { ...value, total: total + 1 },
        ...rolledValues.slice(valueIdx + 1)
      ];
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: you are right, that would work, however, I forgot something important, I execute a bunch of timeouts to simulate a rolling dice. Hence I have to wait till the state is updated until I can update the score keeping array.

Comment: Just call the rollDice function in the timeouts. It'll work especially if you useCallback on it. I'll make that change

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just stick all the logic within `setRolledValues`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!diceNumber) return;

  setRolledValues((prev) => {
    const valueIdx = prev.findIndex(val => val.id === diceNumber);
    const newValue = prev[valueIdx];
    const { total } = newValue;
    newValue.total = total + 1;
    return [
      ...prev.slice(0, valueIdx),
      newValue,
      ...prev.slice(valueIdx + 1)
    ]
  })

}, [diceNumber]);
```

EDIT: As others have pointed out, `useEffect` for this application appears to be ill-suited, as you could simply update `setRolledValues` in your function instead.

If there is some sort of underlying system we're not being shown where you *must* use an observer pattern like this, you can change the datatype of `diceNumber` to an object instead, that way subsequent calls to the same number would trigger `useEffect`

Comment: you are right, that would work, however, I forgot something important, I execute a bunch of timeouts to simulate a rolling dice. Hence I have to wait till the state is updated until I can update the score keeping array.